# Converting all numbers in document to set number of decimal places

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have a table which I need to automatically format all numbers to two decimal places. Is this possible? Or do I need to format the entire document?

EDIT:

I have applied the code suggested in an answer but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for my specific table! Anyone have any ideas on how to adapt it accordingly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{
table-number-alignment = center,
table-figures-integer = 1,
table-figures-decimal = 2
}

\begin{table}[thb]

\caption{\label{labelname}Table Caption}

\scriptsize
{\centering \begin{tabular
{lr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}rr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0.1cm}}cr@{    space{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0.1cm}}cr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0
1cm}}cr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0.1cm}}cr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}r
{\hspace{0.1cm}}cr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0.1cm}}cr@{\hspace{0cm}}c@{\hs
ace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0.1cm}}c}

\\
\hline
Dataset & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ConjunctiveRule }& \multicolumn{4}{c}{DecisionTable } &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{DTNB } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{JRip} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NNge} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{OneR} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PART} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Ridor} \\
\hline
Number correct & 9.5900 & $\pm$ & 1.16 & 9.5600 & $\pm$ & 1.22 &         & 9.5600 & $\pm$ &
1.22 &         & 9.5000 & $\pm$ & 1.24 &         & 8.9500 & $\pm$ & 1.34 &         & 9.6000
& $\pm$ & 1.16 &         & 9.3000 & $\pm$ & 1.34 &         & 9.1700 & $\pm$ & 1.42 &        \

\end{tabular} \scriptsize \par}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem that starts from `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: I get 143, 9, 1, 6 errors when I compile and fix along the way. Please compile your own example (by copying from the question) to test if it is indeed working.

Comment: def works now, just tried it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define each column with decimal figures as an `S`-columns.

You have 31 columns in your tabular, some with decimal, some with a mathematical sign and some empty. In the empty one, I have put a `emdash` (to keep track).

Here is a MWE (minimal working example). I used `scrartcl` with a high DIV-factor and landscape mode to squeeze the tabular in between the margin of a page. You can achieve the same by using the `geometry`-package with correct parametre:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,DIV=20]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{
  table-number-alignment = center,
  table-figures-integer = 1,
  table-figures-decimal = 2
}
\begin{table}[thb]
\caption{\label{labelname}Table Caption}
\centering\tiny
\begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    l
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    l
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    l
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    l
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    c
    S[table-auto-round]
    l}

Dataset & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ConjunctiveRule }& \multicolumn{4}{c}{DecisionTable } &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{DTNB } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{JRip} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NNge} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{OneR} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PART} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Ridor} \\

Number correct & 
9.5900 & 
$\pm$ & 
1.16 & 
9.5600 & 
$\pm$ &
1.22 &
--- &
9.5600 &
$\pm$ &
1.22 &
--- & 
9.5000 & 
$\pm$ & 
1.24 &
--- &
8.9500 & 
$\pm$ &
 1.34 &
--- & 
9.6000 & 
$\pm$ & 
1.16 & 
--- & 
9.3000 & 
$\pm$ 
& 1.34 & 
--- & 
9.1700 & 
$\pm$ &
 1.42 &
--- \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

See page 57 of the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) documentation.

A small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{
  table-number-alignment = center,
  table-figures-integer = 1,
  table-figures-decimal = 2
}
\begin{tabular}{
    S[table-auto-round]
  }
  2.\\
  2.3\\
  2.34\\
  2.345
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the smaple code on its own and it works well! But unfortunately when I apply it to my own table, it doesn't work. I will now post some code in my question